# Fractional float to_datetime

Tags: python, pandas

Why does the following return incorrect seconds and fractional seconds?:

Input:

```
import pandas as pd
pd.to_datetime(float(171638.6), format='%H%M%S%f')
```

Output:

```
Timestamp('1900-01-01 17:16:03.800000')
```

I expected it to return:

```
Timestamp('1900-01-01 17:16:38.600000')
```

I am not sure if this is related:
https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/pull/13847

Comment: `pd.to_datetime(str(171638.6), format='%H%M%S.%f')` seems to give the correct answer. Same goes for `pd.to_datetime(str(float(171638.6)), format='%H%M%S.%f')`.

Comment: The first instance will fail if there is no fractional value, the second instance seems to work in all cases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to work in all cases (with a fraction or without):

```
val1 = 171638.6
pd.to_datetime(f"{val1:f}", format='%H%M%S.%f')
val2 = 171638
pd.to_datetime(f"{val2:f}", format='%H%M%S.%f')
```

so does

```
pd.to_datetime(str(float(val1)), format='%H%M%S.%f')
pd.to_datetime(str(float(val2)), format='%H%M%S.%f')
```